# How to Separate Object From Arrayed Parent

Tags: modeling, animation, parent

To make object scale intact I arrayed a plane around a curve and parented my object to that plane.

It worked but now I need to separate these objects from arrayed plane because I am going to animate them.

I tried to use Clear and Keep Transformation but it did not work in this case.

Comment: Maybe what you want is Ctrl A > Make Instances Real?

Comment: Hello, Hope...  is what you mean: that you have _instanced_ your object on the plane-array, so it isn't deformed by the curve? (I know, it still uses the 'parent' mechanism, so it's a bit confusing)

Comment: @moonboots thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*

Comment: Blender has endless details, it is free so I can not complain much that's why.

Comment: yes it's a bit confusing at the beginning, don't hesistate to take some notes